# Camera2 API is not working in OnePlus 7 Pro

Tags: android-camera2

Getting an exception

W/Binder: Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation.
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$CaptureCallbackHolder.getRequest(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$CameraDeviceCallbacks.onCaptureErrorLocked(CameraDeviceImpl.java:2403)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$CameraDeviceCallbacks.onDeviceError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:2045)
        at android.hardware.camera2.ICameraDeviceCallbacks$Stub.onTransact(ICameraDeviceCallbacks.java:137)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1032)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1005)

Comment: have you found any workaround for this? I am too getting problem in oneplus 6t